# Assign a default value of a label in PHP + HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a PHP + HTML code that generates a contact form:

```
public function doContactForm() {
    ob_start();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
<div id="vue_contact_form_app">
    <div class="basic-message" v-bind:class="{ 'error-message' : status == 'error', 'success-message' : status == 'sent' || status == 'sending' }" v-on:click="closeMessage">
            <p v-show="status != 'clean'">{{ actionMessage }}</p>
    </div>
    <form class="vue-form" @submit.prevent="submit">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="name">Your Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="" maxlength="80" v-model="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="email">Your Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required="" maxlength="40" :class="{ email , error: !email.valid }" v-model="email.value">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="An iteresting idea." required="" maxlength="120" v-model="subject">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="textarea">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="message" name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Dear Mr. Dmitry, ..." required="" v-model="message.text" :maxlength="message.maxlength"></textarea>
                <span class="counter">{{ message.text.length }} / {{ message.maxlength }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $this->getOption('PublicKey');?>"></div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

How to initialize `Your Name` field with `$current_user->user_email` if `$current_user` is set? What attribute should assign and what is the syntax?

Comment: I would use a ternary here.

Comment: "_value of a label_"... What is that supposed to mean? `<label>`s don't use a value attribute

Comment: FYI: Functions shouldn't be responsible to output content, they should return a value. Also why are you using `ob_start` directly in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant the textbox rather than the label, since labels don't have values.

You can inject the data into the `value` property of the HTML `input` element, but testing first (using a ternary operator) whether the object is set or not.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="" maxlength="80" v-model="name" value="<?php echo (isset($current_user) ? $current_user->user_email : "" ?>">
```

Comment: Even if I do this `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="" maxlength="80" v-model="name" value="Dmitry">` I do not see "Dmitry". Probably it is handled by vue.js somehow.

Comment: Ah yes, perhaps. The involvement of vue.js wasn't mentioned in your question. If you have a problem with that scenario, I would suggest making a new question about that, with a [mre] of that specific issue. Hope this answer helped in the meantime.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76761327/input-field-default-value-in-vue-js

Comment: Ah good. However, I know absolutely nothing about Vue so I'll leave answering that to someone else :-)